# Error in JsonObjectRequest in volley library

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I am trying to implement a JsonRequestObject with Volley library on android

this is the code of the method

```
private void makeJsonObjReq() {
    showProgressDialog();
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,
            Const.URL_JSON_OBJECT, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    msgResponse.setText(response.toString());
                    hideProgressDialog();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    hideProgressDialog();
                }
            }) {
```

and this is the error message

> Error:(71, 34) error: reference to JsonObjectRequest is ambiguous
>   both constructor JsonObjectRequest(int,String,String,Listener,ErrorListener) in JsonObjectRequest and constructor JsonObjectRequest(int,String,JSONObject,Listener,ErrorListener) in JsonObjectRequest match

Comment: where is semicolon after ErrorListener ends

Comment: i didn't put all the code, just the part of code that contain the error.

Comment: anyways but passing null should work I do the same thing and it works

Comment: you work on eclipse or android studio ??
i downloaded this code from a tutorial working on eclipse and i am working on android studio

Comment: download code from git and created jar working in android studio

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try passing blank string in constructor instead of null.

```
private void makeJsonObjReq() {
showProgressDialog();
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,
        Const.URL_JSON_OBJECT, "",
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                msgResponse.setText(response.toString());
                hideProgressDialog();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                hideProgressDialog();
            }
        }) {
```

The reason it was not working is because when you pass parameters in constructor, it tries to match them with available constructors on three basic criterias:

1. The total number of parameters you have passed.
2. The ordering of those parameters like (int, String, int);
3. And the type of parameter passed.

In your case, based on above conditions it matched to two constructors. The value of String or JSONObject can be null thats why it was showing you ambiguous error on JsonObjectRequest(int,String,String,Listener,ErrorListener) and JsonObjectRequest(int,String,JSONObject,Listener,ErrorListener). We just passed blank String as argument so that it now knows that the third argument is of type string.